# A sorted ComputingMap?

Tags: java, guava, sortedmap

How can I construct a SortedMap on top of [Guava's computing map](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) (or vice versa)? I want the sorted map keys as well as computing values on-the-fly.

Comment: It is not clear how the iterator of computing map is supposed to behave.

Comment: Neither is it clear what the semantics of a sorted computing map should be.

Comment: @OrangeDog, The map should provide "weakly consistent iteration" as discussed in MapMaker's Javadoc. The only difference would be that keys would be sorted according to natural order or using a Comparator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is probably to use a ConcurrentSkipListMap and the memoizer idiom (see JCiP), rather than relying on the pre-built unsorted types from MapMaker. An example that you could use as a basis is a [decorator](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/SelfPopulatingCache) implementation.

Comment: I don't understand how this results in the map keys being sorted.

Comment: @Gili, ConcurrentSkipListMap is a concurrent, sorted map.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do something like this.It's not a complete implementation.Just a sample to convey the idea.

```
public class SortedComputingMap<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, V> {
    private Function<K, V> function;
    private int maxSize;

    public SortedComputingMap(int maxSize, Function<K, V> function) {
        this.function = function;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        V tmp = null;
        K Key = (K) key;
        if ((tmp = super.get(key)) == null) {

            super.put(Key, function.apply(Key));
        }
        if (size() > maxSize)
            pollFirstEntry();
        return tmp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Long> sortedMap = new SortedComputingMap<Integer, Long>(3,
                new Function<Integer, Long>() {
                    @Override
                    public Long apply(Integer n) {
                        Long fact = 1l;
                        while (n != 0)
                            fact *= n--;
                        return fact;
                    }
                });

        sortedMap.get(12);
        sortedMap.get(1);
        sortedMap.get(2);
        sortedMap.get(5);

        System.out.println(sortedMap.entrySet());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the thread safety, this could be tricky, but if you don't I'd recommend something close to Emil's suggestion, but using a `ForwardingSortedMap` rather than extending `TreeMap` directly.